# Trying to copy data from a closed workbook to a current workbook

Tags: vba, excel

Sub Testing()
    Dim Target_Workbook As Workbook
    Dim Source_Workbook As Workbook
    Dim Target_Path As String
    Target_Path = "Sample.xlsx"
    Set Target_Workbook = Workbooks.Open(Target_Path)
    Set Source_Workbook = ThisWorkbook
    Source_data = Source_Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1:Y74").Copy
    Target_Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Activate
    Source_Workbook.Save
    Target_Workbook.Save
    Target_Workbook.Close False
    MsgBox "Task Completed"
End Sub

Comment: So.. what is the question?

Answer (score 0):

use below code, populate your source and target excel file names and call this code

```
Sub CopyWorkbook(Sourceworkbook, TargetWorkbook)
Dim sh As Worksheet, wb As Workbook, wbSource As Workbook
Dim SourcefileName As String

SourcefileName = Sourceworkbook

Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(Sourceworkbook)
Set wb = Workbooks(TargetWorkbook)
For Each sh In Workbooks(SourcefileName).Worksheets
   sh.Copy After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.count)
Next sh

wbSource.Close

End Sub
```

e.g TargetWorkbook = "TwoSheet_Compare V2.0.xlsm" and 
SourceWorkbook = "sourceFile.xlsx"